# Getting warning from props passed in MUI styled components related to React not recognizing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I have a styled component that needs to receive props to decide how it should be styled. Looks something like this:

```js
const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)(
  ({ myColor = "black", isLarge = false }) => ({
    "&&": {
      fontSize: isLarge ? 30 : 16,
      border: `1px solid ${myColor}`,
      margin: 10,
      color: myColor
    }
  })
);
```

Unfortunately `isLarge` causes the following warning:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `isLarge` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `islarge` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

(Same with `myColor`)

In another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71415785/pass-in-external-styles-to-a-mui-styled-component), I was told that all that needs to be done is to use `shouldForwardProp` as a function returning a boolean in the second parameter to decide what props should be passed in tot the DOM DOM:

```js
const StyledTypography = styled(Typography, { shouldForwardProp: () => false })(
 ...
);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Is there anyway to do this?

Here is a working sample app with the warnings and everything: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fast-qll47?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const StyledTypography = styled(Typography, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "myColor" && prop !== "isLarge"
})(
  ...
);

const StyledButton = styled(Button, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "myColor"
})(
  ...
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not make a difference :( Even if I put a console.log in the function, it is never called.

Comment: change import styled from @emotion package

Comment: That did it! Thanks fo much! and on a side note... How confusing on which one to use. Anyway, now I know :)

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue with a custom prop on component created with `styled` from `@material-ui/core/styles` and it nearly drove me crazy. Using MUI 4.11 the solution with the `@emotion/styled` did not work for me.

As a solution that worked, I created an intermediate component that doesn't pass the custom props to the DOM.

In the case above, it will look something like

```js
const TypographyComponent = ({myColor, isLarge, ...props}) => <Typography {...props} />;
 
const StyledTypography = styled(TypographyComponent)(
  ({ myColor = "black", isLarge = false }) => ({
    "&&": {
      fontSize: isLarge ? 30 : 16,
      border: `1px solid ${myColor}`,
      margin: 10,
      color: myColor
    }
  })
);
```

For me this was a viable solution, hope this will help others as well

Answer (score 1):

## Customizing prop forwarding in Emotion

---

use **isPropValid** from **@emotion/is-prop-valid**

### Example:

```js
import isPropValid from '@emotion/is-prop-valid'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const H1 = styled('h1', {
  shouldForwardProp: prop => isPropValid(prop) && prop !== 'color'
})(props => ({
  color: props.color
}))

render(<H1 color="lightgreen">This is lightgreen.</H1>)
```

**NOTE**:
for **Typescript** do the following:

```js
const H1 = styled('h1', {
  shouldForwardProp: prop => typeof prop === "string" && isPropValid(prop)
})(props => ({
  color: props.color
}))
```

check the **[docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#customizing-prop-forwarding)**

Answer (score 0):

There is a more-or-less universal way of using `shouldForwardProp` based on styled-components behaviour: we name our internal props starting with $ and they're not being forwarded to the component being styled (`div` in my example).

```
export const SidebarList = styled('div', styledOmit$PropsOptions)<{ $isCompact: boolean }>(({ $isCompact }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexGrow: 1,
    gap: "16px",
    padding: !$isCompact ? "8px 16px" : "8px",
    transitionProperty: "padding",
    transitionDuration: "0.5s",
}));
```

the filtering is based on the function `shouldForwardProp` in options:

```
export const styledOmit$PropsOptions = {
    shouldForwardProp: (propName: string) => !propName.startsWith('$')
};
```

docs on passing the options to the MUI `styled`: https://mui.com/system/styled/#custom-components